# Error : upgrade magento 2.2.6 to magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.2.6, magento-upgrade

Error : upgrade magento 2.2.6 to magento 2.3.0

To upgrade the website, I used the following blog
https://www.webcreta.com/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-2-x-to-2-3-0/

But when I run the composer update command, I got the following error
[image]

I checked all solutions on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ but I can't found any solution.

Please suggest a solution.

Thank you so much.